# Silverlight Dataform DeleteItem problem

Tags: silverlight

I have a toolbar control in my application. Delete an item from dataform from toolbar delete button. After this apply submitchanges() method. Delete Item work fine but source.HasChange is always false so submitchanges doesn't work fine. no deleting from Database.
Plase help thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find your answer in 
http://cid-1bf46693be07cfa6.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/DeleteThroughDataForm.zip
sample